# Finding points from shapefile (residing in GeoServer) that are inside a provided polygon

Tags: geoserver, filter, point-in-polygon, gml

I am new to GeoServer and spatial data. I have a shapefile "shape-file-2" in geo server which is a collection of **Points**. I am trying to fetch all the points which are inside a provided polygon.

I am using this API

`http://localhost:8888/geoserver/wfs`

with body

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
  outputFormat="JSON"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:fes='http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0'
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                      http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="aw:shape-file-2">
<fes:Filter>
            
                <fes:Within>
                    <ValueReference>the_geom</ValueReference>
                    <!-- gml:id is mandatory on GML 3.2 geometry elements -->
                    <gml:Polygon srsName='http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326'>
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                <gml:posList srsDimension="2">-71.89601791 42.07223825 -71.06278329 42.07223825 -71.06278329 42.52509234 -71.89601791 42.52509234 -71.89601791 42.07223825
</gml:posList>
                            </gml:LinearRing>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </fes:Within>
            <fes:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

I am getting this exception in response

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport
   version="1.2.0"
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
    <ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for LinearRing: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find coordinates to build linestring
Parsing failed for LinearRing: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find coordinates to build linestring
Could not find coordinates to build linestring
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I am able to get the required output using **GET** call

http://localhost:8888/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=json&typeNames=aw:shape-file-2&&cql_filter=WITHIN (the_geom,SRID=4326;POLYGON((-71.89601791 42.07223825,-71.06278329 42.07223825,-71.06278329 42.52509234,-71.89601791 42.52509234 ,-71.89601791 42.07223825)))

But I need to fire the POST call because polygon co-ordinates can be huge and I will not able to pass in the query string

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GML 3 and Filter 2.0 in a WFS 1.0.0 request and I suspect that is confusing GeoServer. Try changing your `wfs` definitions to:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="2.0.0"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd
    http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
```

and see if it works better.

Failing that you'll need to turn logging up and look in the log file to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Turton error is gone but returned feature collection is 0 whereas with Filter 1.0 I am getting correct result now. Workspace import was missing that also I have included now. Can you point out any other mistake ?

Comment: lon/lat instead of lat/lon in your coordinates?

Comment: I corrected it and it is working now. Not sure why I was getting the correct result with the same input with Filter 1. Let me know If you have any idea. Thanks